# Ajax Load Div based on URI (Instead of onClick)

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am converting an old web application. In the legacy version, there is a page which displays some default content when the user navigates to it. There is a link within that page which reloads the page but with a querystring `showform=yes` which causes a form to be displayed instead of the content.

In the old version, the page was like this:

- `http://site.com/directory.asp` - for the main page with the content
- `http://site.com/directory.asp?showform=yes` - called when the user
  clicked the button to show the form.

In the new version of the web app, that same page is set up with ajax, in that there is a div which contains the default content when someone visits `http://site.com/directory`. There is a button, which, when clicked (from within that page), some ajax is invoked which swaps out the content and displays the form. There is no change in the URI/querystring.

Here is my question - In the legacy version of the web app, there are some other pages which link the user directly to the page with the form (`http://site.com/directory.asp?showform=yes`) e.g. so they don't need to click the button once the arrive at directory.asp.

Is there a what I can mimimc this behavior based on how I have that page set up now e.g. displaying the form via ajax in a div?)

Initially I thought that perhaps ajax can be triggered based on the presence of a querystring or an anchor in the URI e.g. `/directory#form` but I am not sure if that is possible.

I would prefer a solution that is not dependent on jQuery, but will consider it if there are no other options.

Thanks in advance for looking, and please let me know if I can further clarify.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can trigger AJAX call on the basis of a boolean variable which you can set through the query string. 
The default value for the boolean variable is false which forces the user to click on the button to refresh the form section.

But when the comes back on the same page the query string will set the boolean variable to true whereby the javascript function containing the AJAX code is invoked from your JSP/ASP or HTML.

Comment: How would this type of thing actually be implemented?  

I am envisioning something like this:  Lets say we have a querystring present, and based on that, a block of javascript is created which triggers the ajax call on the loading of the page?

Is that the type of thing you were suggesting?

Comment: SO I tried to implement this, but it didn't work, i think because the window.onLoad triess to find the function (which is defined in a .js include) too early, it throws a `Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlhttpPost is not defined 
(anonymous function)
` error, even though the function works fine when called from , say,  a button's onclick attribute.

Comment: call window.onLoad at the bottom of your JSP/HTMl file so that all the required JS files are loaded before and also you can add the defer attribute to the script element. Otherwise use some JS library like prototype or jQuery to call the onload feature of browser which will be a better cross platform solution.